# FB like placement changes in IE6

Tags: facebook

I have implemented FB like button in my page.. It works fine in all browsers but not in IE6.
In IE6 firstly it comes fine and then after a few seconds it shifts to left..

Thank in advance for the help...

Comment: Why do you have to support IE6? Its browser share is currently dropping fast and many websites no longer officially support it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah IE its a pain, maybe you can load some css on browser detected

```
<!--[if IE 6]>

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/somecss_for_ie6.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```